# react-native-video video on demand dash or hls streaming from cloudfront

Tags: react-native, react-native-video

I have mpd and m3u8 files on S3 and distributed through CloudFront. When I test streaming using bitmovin.com, flowplayer.com it works. React-native-video component shows `{error:{extra:-214748348, what:1}}` `onError` callback.

Comment: facing the same issue. any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I make downgrade to version 4.4.4. It worked for me.
Code example:

```
       <Video
            onError={this.onError}
            onBuffer={this.onBuffer} 
            onProgress={this.onProgress}
            type="mp4"
            source={{uri: "http://d23dyxeqlo5psv.cloudfront.net/big_buck_bunny.mp4"}}
            ref={(ref) => {
              this.player = ref
            }}
            style={{ alignSelf: 'stretch', height: 300 }}
          />
```